# jQuery loop though two levels of elements

Tags: jquery, html, loops, foreach

I have some html that looks like this:

```
<div class="block">
    <div id="item1"></div>
    <div id="item2"></div>
</div>

<div class="block">
    <div id="item3"></div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to check to see if my div will contain a specific element. I need to loop though each block, *then* get each item.

What I've got so far

```
    $('.block:has(div)').each(function() {
            // do something with the block
    });
```

Which is great, because it will return all the blocks that have items in them. But I need something along the lines of

```
    $('.block:has(div)').each(function() {
             $('current place in loop' + li).each(function() {
                    // do something with each item element, before the block loop has finished
             });
    });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if this answers what you are asking, but wouldn't the following work:

```
$('.block:has(div)').each(function() {
  $(this).children('div').each(function() {
    // do something with each item element, before the block loop has finished
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I hope you mean this:

```
$('.block').each(function(){
    $(this).find('div').each(function(){
        //do your stuff
    });
});
```

Comment: Yep that's exactly what I did mean, works as I thought it should :)

Comment: be aware that that will find all <div> elements under the parent element, at any level. Use children() to get direct children only.

Answer (score 2):

I would build the selector within the nested each, or use find:

```
 $('.block:has(div)').each(function() {
     $('#' + this.id +  ' li').each(function() {
         //do stuff on list item            
     });
 });
```

OR

```
 $('.block:has(div)').each(function() {
     $(this).find('li').each(function() {
         //do stuff on list item            
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using

```
$("#" + this)
```

?
It's used in the main each example of jquery documentation 
(harshath has already posted... too slow, *sob*)